# Получение и изменение содержимого полей формы javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть такая форма:

```html
<form id="calc">
  <select name="choice">
    <option value="1">Вариант 1</option>
    <option value="2">Вариант 2</option>
    <option value="3">Вариант 3</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  <input type="text" name="num" size="20" maxlength="20"></input>
  </br>
  <input disabled name="result" id="result"></input>
  </br>
  <button value="submit" onclick=()>Result</button>
</form>
```

и есть некая переменная `var a=1`

*Вопрос 1.* Как изменить содержимое поля `result` на значение этой переменной?

*Вопрос 2.* Как реализовать проверку выбора в блоке `<select>`? К примеру, если выбран элемент со значение `value=1`, то будет выполняться некая функция.

*Вопрос 3.* Как получить значение поля `num` и занести его в переменную `b`?

Comment: создал такой скрипт
  `<script text="text/javascript">  
var a=1;  
var b;  
document.getElementById('result').result.value = a;  
</script>`  
Никакого эффекта. 
В чем проблема?

Comment: потому, что вместо `getElementById('result')` надо было написать `getElementById('calc')`

Comment: @tutankhamun написал,как вы сказали. По прежнему никакого результата

Comment: Странно. Тут https://jsfiddle.net/m4zofycv/ работает. В каком браузере проверяете (хотя должно почти везде работать)?

Comment: @tutankhamun https://codeshare.io/Lk2ij вот полный код моей странички. Может я что-то не так делаю?
Браузер Хром

Comment: Не так то, что у вас скрипт находится выше элементов, которые он адресует. На момент выполнения скрипта их еще нету. В консоли Javascript должны появляться ошибки (обращайте на них внимание). Либо запускайте скрипт после загрузки DOM, либо переместите блок `<script>` после формы

Comment: @tutankhamun про перемещение я понял, а как сделать чтобы загрузка происходила поле загрузки DOM?

Comment: Почитайте про события `DOMContentLoaded` и `load` объекта `window` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то примерно так:

1. `document.getElementById('calc').result.value = a;`
2. `document.getElementById('calc').choice.addEventListener('change', function(e) { if (1 == this.value) doMyFunction(); });`
3. `var b = document.getElementById('calc').num.value;`

Поясню:

1. `document.getElementById(id)` - получение элемента c указанным `id`;
2. Исторически сложилось, что у элементов `<form>` есть волшебное свойство. Оно позволяет обращаться к полям ввода формы непосредственно по имени самого поля, как к свойствам этого объекта (по сути идет обращение к коллекции `elements`);
3. У каждого элемента `<input>` есть свойство `value`, которое содержит текущее значение этого элемента.

Comment: doMyFunction это, как я понял, название функции? И нужно перед этим описать ее. К примеру я хочу чтобы функция меняла значение переменной. Я написал так `function doMyFunction(){
   choice=5;
  }
  document.getElementById('calc').choice.addEventListener('change', function(e) { if (1 == this.value) doMyFunction(); });` , но ничего не работает, почему?

Comment: @jon4eg Смотря что вы хотите получить. `choice=5` не влияет на `<select>`. См. пункт 1 моего ответа